# Target transformation and feature selection. ValueError: Input X contains NaN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection, rfe

I am using RFECV for feature selection in scikit-learn. I would like to run an XGBoost model with log(y) because I have been able to demonstrate that this is performing better than just y.

Simple model without transformation: no problem, RFECV works fine and I can get the number of features.

Log-transformed model = problem: I have an error saying:

> "ValueError: Input X contains NaN; RFECV does not accept missing
> values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might
> want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and
> Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively.
> Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by
> using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with
> missing values. See
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a
> list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page:
> [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values"](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values%22)

What I don't understand is that I do not have a NaN issue with the simple model but I do with the log-transformed one. I do not have NaN in the target y.

How can I solve my problem and be able to run RFECV with a log-transformed target?

```
# Base estimator
rs = 45
xgboost_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(random_state = rs, 
                                grow_policy = "depthwise", 
                                booster = "gbtree", # gblinear or dart; gbtree and dart use tree based models while gblinear uses linear functions.
                                tree_method = "auto", # pick best option between hist, exact and approx
                                n_estimators = randint(300,500).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                subsample = uniform(0.5, 0.5).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                max_depth = randint(3,10).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                learning_rate = loguniform(0.05, 0.2).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                colsample_bytree = uniform(0.5, 0.5).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                min_child_weight =  randint(1,20).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                gamma = uniform(0.5, 1).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                reg_alpha = uniform(0.0, 1.0).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                reg_lambda = uniform(0.0, 1.0).rvs(random_state = rs),
                                max_delta_step = randint(1,10).rvs(random_state = rs)
)

# RFECV settings
n_features = 89
step = 20
n_scores = 2
min_features_to_select = 9

# Simple model = working
rfecv = RFECV(
    xgboost_reg,
    step=step,
    cv=4,
    scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error",
    min_features_to_select= min_features_to_select,
    n_jobs=-1, 
)
rfecv.fit(x, y)
print(rfecv.n_features_)

# Log-transformed model = error
log_estimator = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=xgboost_reg,
                                             func=np.log,
                                             inverse_func=np.exp)
rfecv_log = RFECV(
    estimator= log_estimator,
    step=step,
    cv=4,
    scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error",
    min_features_to_select= min_features_to_select,
    n_jobs=-1, 
)
rfecv_log.fit(x, y)
print(rfecv_log.n_features_)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised Answer**: The error is due to x containing Nan values. The problem can be resolved by updating scikit-learn to the current version 1.4.0, which allows Nan values in RFECV.

*Note: The original suggestion was to check for negative values in the target, as `np.log()` for negative numbers produces nan values, which was not the cause of the problem.*

Comment: Hi Wieland, thank you for your suggestion (and welcome to SO !). However, I do not have 0 nor negative values in the target.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! What scikit-learn version are you using? I reproduced the error with your code when I changed one value of x to np.Nan. The first fit worked, the second threw the error. I could resolve the issue by updating to the latest scikit-learn version 1.4.0.

Comment: Thank you @Wieland ! It was that easy... I spent a lot of time on this instead of just updating sklearn. You could add this mention in your first answer or make another answer and I'll accept it !